# Does Qt offer a (guaranteed) debug definition?

Tags: debugging, qt, definition

Does anyone know an officially supported way to include debug-build only code in Qt? For example:

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
// do something
#endif
```

Basically like Q_ASSERT but for more complex tests.

I can't seem to find any documentation which says that the Qt framework guarantees to define a debug macro. If there isn't, what would be a sensible *unofficial* way to implement this feature project wide?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Qt defines `QT_NO_DEBUG` for release builds. Otherwise `QT_DEBUG` is defined.

Of course you are free to specify any `DEFINES` in your .pro files and scope them for either `debug` or `release`.

Comment: Do you know of any evidence that `QT_NO_DEBUG` is officially supported for use outside the Qt framework?

Comment: No, just reading the source. Though it's unlikely that definitions in published API headers are changed without a very good reason.

Answer (score 22):

An alternative is to write in your project file something like:

```
debug {
  DEFINES += MYPREFIX_DEBUG
}
release {
  DEFINES += MYPREFIX_RELEASE
}
```

Then you will not depend on the Qt internal definition.

Comment: Not an unreasonable suggestion but I was **specifically** looking to avoid additional definitions.

Comment: Why? What disadvantages do you see in additional define?

Comment: This way, both can be defined, which is probably not wanted. Use e.g. CONFIG(debug,debug|release) to check for debug builds, see: https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#What_does_the_syntax_CONFIG.28debug.2Cdebug.7Crelease.29_mean_.3F_What_does_the_1st_argument_specify_and_similarly_what_is_the_2nd_.3F

Answer (score 9):

For check debug mode:

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    //Some codes
#endif
```

For check release mode:

```
#ifndef QT_DEBUG    //<== Please note... if not defined
    //Some codes
#endif
```