# How to deterimine if debugging in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging

I am working with Linux and Qt. I want to compile certain code only if we are debugging. In Windows I am used to doing the following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
..code...
#endif
```

This however does not work. I am compiling the debug build and not the release build. What is the way to not compile certain pieces of code in release, but compile them when debug build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Qt offer a (guaranteed) debug definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801584/does-qt-offer-a-guaranteed-debug-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#ifdef QT_DEBUG

..code...

#endif