# Can not surpress QDebug output in relesae build

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, qdebug

I work on a Qt project and I use cmake. In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        QT_DEBUG_NO_OUTPUT
        QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT
        QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT
        )
```

and to test that in my main.cpp I have:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    qDebug() << "QDEBUG IS ACTIVE!";
    std::cout << "Compiled in DEBUG\n";
#else
    qDebug() << "QDEBUG IS ACTIVE!";
    std::cout << "Compiled in RELEASE\n";
#endif
```

Does not matter if I compile in Release or Debug configuration, the line "QDEBUG IS ACTIVE!" gets printed.

P.S. I get correct cout for release and debug, so the configurations are working!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use the logging category filter rules and make it based on a setting or command line argument: `QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(...);` You can turn on and off specific types of messages.

Comment: Or you can try [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801584/does-qt-offer-a-guaranteed-debug-definition)

Comment: "Does not matter if I compile in Release or Debug configuration, the line "QDEBUG IS ACTIVE!" gets printed." - This is expectable, as you have the **same line** `qDebug() << "QDEBUG IS ACTIVE!";` in both `#ifndef` and `#else` branches.

Comment: @Tsyvarev No! it should not print, the point is I expect it not to print anything!

Comment: If you expect `qDebug` to print nothing, then you should define `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` macro (not a `QT_DEBUG_NO_OUTPUT` as in your current code).

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah I was using the wrong macro apparently and the one you said is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the typo QT_DEBUG_NO_OUTPUT to QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT in order to use qDebug.

If you want to disable qDebug, qInfo and qWarning for a Release build only, then add the following condition to CMakeLists.txt:

```
string(TOLOWER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} build_type)
if (build_type STREQUAL release)
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
        QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT
        QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT
        )
endif()
```

Comment: Oh man! I the defines I was using are wrong! maybe they belong to Qt4? I picked them from an old page in google. Thanks!